# XML within a TextField in ActionScript3

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3, comments, textfield

I made a simple project which you paste XML into a TextField and and uses this. It works great however it doesn't keep the original structure which wasn't much of a problem until i recently noticed if i load or copy and paste XML which contain comments like:

```
    //<min>0.0</min>
    //<max>255.0</max>
```

In the TextField it turns to this:

```
//
<min>0.0</min>
//
<max>255.0</max>
```

Which creates problems as from what i can tell it would then run lines of code it should not. I would prefer if it kept the same text structure as the loading/copy and paste method seems to adjust it for some reason.

So my main question is can you keep the exact same XML text structure with working comments?

Another problem i noticed is when the XML is in the TextField it removes this part:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

So my other questions are why does it remove that rather than keeping the text exactly the same? and can i make it keep that or would i have to manually append that text again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to look at [XML.ignoreProcessingInstructions](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html#ignoreProcessingInstructions), [XML.ignoreComments](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html#ignoreComments), [XML.prettyPrinting](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html#prettyPrinting), [XML.prettyIndent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html#prettyIndent) and [XML.ignoreWhitespace](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html#ignoreWhitespace).

Also, the double slash `//` does not mark comments in XML - they should look like this:

```
<!-- this is a comment -->
```

Comment: Thanks, these seem like just what i need to fix the problems.